# Setting up Serilog for AzureFunction

Tags: c#, azure-functions, serilog, seq-logging

I'm relatively new to C# and Azure and this thing confuses me to no end. What I want is to log everything Information+ to Seq, and to override MS/System to Warning+.

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(SillyApp.Startup))]

namespace SillyApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .WriteTo.Seq("https://blahblah.bla")
                .CreateLogger();

            builder.Services.AddLogging(b => { b.AddSerilog(logger); });
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that I've now added a Serilog-provider to the logging Providers. This works in that Seq receives, but the overrides does nothing. The Minimumlevel.Information does work however.

SillyApp.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SillyApp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

        public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("TimedThing")]
        public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")] TimerInfo timer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Helloes");
        }
    }
}
```

My *theory* is that logging providers now include both the default one and the Serilog one. And somehow they combine and make my life a misery. What shows up in Seq is a whole bunch of stuff. Executed messages, "1 function loaded", "Host Initialized/started". Tagged as Information, but doesn't even show in my Run Window.

So if my theory is correct, how do I override the default logging provider? If I'm mistaken then can someone please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Not all Serilog features work with `AddSerilog()`, minimum level overrides are one of those.

In regular apps, `UseSerilog()` (the newer API) on `IHostBuilder` will work correctly with all Serilog features.

Unfortunately, I don't think Azure Function apps give you an `IHostBuilder` to work with.

The better alternative will be to use *Seq.Extensions.Logging* (`dotnet add package Seq.Extensions.Logging`) instead of Serilog, and to write to Seq using:

```cs
        services.AddLogging(b => b.AddSeq("https://blahblah.bla"));
```

You will then be able to use *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging* level overrides in your `appsettings.json` configuration file:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "Seq": {
      "ServerUrl": "https://blahblah.bla",
      "ApiKey": "1234567890",
      "LogLevel": {
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```